# Cookie array in data attribute to get value and display in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i call data/listing.json directly it works fine.

```
<div data-endfavpoint="data/listing.json" data-expiring-days="3" data-new-days="7" data-brand="" data-property="" data-hide="false" class="component">.....</div>
```

Issue here, i want to call Cookie array value parsed in JSON Format like below using JSON.parse. But, getting error because of JSON.parse($.cookie('offer')) code.

```
<div data-endfavpoint="JSON.parse($.cookie('offer'))" data-expiring-days="3" data-new-days="7" data-brand="" data-property="" data-hide="false" class="component">....</div>
```

Please let me know how to call JSON.parse($.cookie('offer')) inside data attribute and display values inside div.

[image]

Comment: HTML attributes always accepts string as values but JSON.parse() returns a javascript object which can't be accepted as node attribute value.

Comment: Why do you want to use JSON.parse() when it is already working in first case?

Comment: --- data-endfavpoint="javascript:JSON.parse($.cookie('offer'))" -- might help you.

Comment: RK_15: JSON format is for testing whether values are displaying correctly. But, for this case we are storing all values in cookie as array. Instead .json instead to call Cookie JSON parser to display the contents how it displays with .json inside data attribute.

Comment: How is data stored in cookie('offer')? is it string or object?

Comment: can I see content of lisiting.json file. I want to see if string has object representation or array representation

Comment: @Dohab Object. Please check attached screenshot.

Comment: @RK_15 please check attached screenshot. I need to trigger this data attribute to display the content

Comment: Use $.cookie('favouriteOffer') instead of JSON.parse( $.cookie('favouriteOffer')) and check. In my opinion this $.cookie('favouriteOffer') is already a JSON formatted string.

Comment: I agree with @RK_15, its already in json format. just load the cookie directly.

Comment: @RK_15  Yes correct.. i too want to call cookie directly. My issue here, how to call this cookie inside data attribute like i am calling "data/listing.json"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would set attribute in a script, since you use jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".component").attr("data-endfavpoint", $.cookie("offer"));
    });
</script>
```